# What does this if statement do? (string comparison)

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand a piece of code which loops over a file, does various assignments, then enters a set of if statements where a string is seemingly compared to nothing. What are `/nonsynonymous/` and `/prematureStop/` being compared to here? I am mostly experienced with python.

```
open(IN,$file);
    while(<IN>){
        chomp $_;
        my @tmp = split /\t+/,$_;
        my $id = join("\t",$tmp[0],$tmp[1]-1);
        $id =~ s/chr//;
        my @info_field = split /;/,$tmp[2];
        my $vat = $info_field[$#info_field];
        my $score = 0;
        $self -> {VAT} ->{$id}= $vat;
        $self ->{GENE} -> {$id} = $tmp[3];
        if (/nonsynonymous/ || /prematureStop/){...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is comparing against the current input line ($_).

By default, perl will automatically use the current input line ($_) when doing regex matches unless overridden (with =~).

Answer (score 4):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

> If you're matching against the special default variable $_ , the $_ =~
>   part can be omitted:

```
$_ = "Hello World";
if (/World/) {
    print "It matches\n";
}
else {
    print "It doesn't match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Often in Perl, if a specific variable isn't given, it's assumed that you want to use the default variable `$_`. For instance, the while loop assigns the incoming lines from `<IN>` to that variable, `chomp $_;` could just as well have been written `chomp;`, and the regular expressions in the if statement try to match with `$_` as well.